# When is from_db_value called in Django 1.8?

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

In the Django 1.8 release notes, it mentions that Django Fields no longer use `SubfieldBase`, and has replaced the `to_python` call on assignment with `from_db_value`.

The docs also state that `from_db_value` is called whenever data is loaded from the database.

My question is, is `from_db_value` called if I directly read/write the db (i.e. using cursor.execute())? My initial tries and intuition says no, but I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [The Django Documentation for Executing custom SQL directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

> Sometimes even `Manager.raw()` isn’t quite enough: you might need to perform queries that don’t map cleanly to models, or directly execute UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE queries.
>
> In these cases, you can always access the database directly, routing around the model layer entirely.

The above states that using `cursor.execute()` will bypass the model logic entirely, returning the raw row results.

If you want to perform raw queries and return model objects, see [the Django Documentation on Performing raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries).

> The raw() manager method can be used to perform raw SQL queries that return model instances:

```
for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person'):
    print(p)

>>> John Smith
>>> Jane Jones
```